# Which places I could question about TFS, Visual Studio and ALM?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, alm

We are going to applying VSTS 2010 in our company. This includes Visual Studio, TFS, TFS Build and ALM. It's predictable that we would encounter a wave of new questions about their usage.

But the problem is I don't know which places we could do questioning. StackOverflow is programming base question site and ServerFault is not very active. How do you think about? Which places and their advantages and disadvantages?

afsharm

Comment: This question belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com, where questions _about_ the site and its usage belong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could ask your questions here, there is already a handful of question on [tfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs), [visual-studio](http://visual-studio) and [msbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msbuild).

You could also ask on [Team System forum MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/category/vsts). (Or both)

Answer (score 2):

We are trying to start a Visual Studio ALM community on Stack Exchange that is dedicated to these questions.

If you want to join in you can [Commit to the Visual Studio ALM](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15894/visual-studio-alm?referrer=vtx1N5_bjYysH8mQCaDCxQ2) proposal.

Comment: why your are trying migrate TFS and Visual Studio questions from here to Stack Exchange? It seems there is many quesion about VS ALM here.

Comment: This is Stack Exchange, and Stack Overflow is realy ment for programming questions. Having a dedicated community is not a bad thing...

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you wait for the ALM site to get to beta these sites/blogs might help you:

- [The WoodwardWeb](http://www.woodwardweb.com/) this is a very useful site for me.
- [Brian Harrys TFS blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry)

Comment: also look at:

 - [Radio TFS][1]
 - [Microsofts ALM pages][1]

  [1]: http://feeds.feedburner.com/radiotfs
  [2]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff625779.aspx